# Polynomial representing a sequence of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence of integers $1,3,5,7,9,\cdots$ can be generated by a polynomial in $n$. Precisely, $p(n)=2n-1$ gives rise to it.

However, the sequence $1,2,6,24,\cdots, n!,\cdots$ cannot be generated by a polynomial.

How would one know, if some sequence of numbers, say $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots,a_n,\cdots$ can be generated by a polynomial?

Comment: $n!$ grows too fast.  If you can show that $a_n$ grows faster than some exponential, then there is no polynomial that works.  In general, you can find the degree of the polynomial by looking at the growth rate and then you can check to see if it does in fact match such a polynomial.

Comment: Depends on how you define the sequence (how do you define $1,3,5,7,9$ as a sequence?), but if you're just given an arbitrary sequence $a_n$, you can form the sequence of finite differences $a_n - a_{n-1}$, and the sequence of finite differences of this sequence $(a_n - a_{n-1}) - (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})$,  and so on. If you hit a sequence consisting entirely of zeros at some finite point, then your first sequence is a polynomial (in fact, of a degree specified by the point at which you get a sequence of zeros). Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: Sarvesh, what is this result? Reference?

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala [Here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/) is a proof that if you have a polynomial of degree $k$, then the $k$th finite difference is a constant (hence the $k+1$th finite difference is a sequence of zeros). The converse is also there : if you have an entire row of the difference table, you can reconstruct the initial function, and if an entire row is zero it is clear that the function thus constructed is a polynomial of the desired degree. That theorem is written for polynomials, but you can replace $f(n)$ with just $a_n$, for example.

Comment: @Sarvesh, Thank you for the reference and the effort.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n$ follows a polynomial of degree $d$, then the first order difference $b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$ follows a polynomial of degree $d-1$. So if you iterate this $d$ times, you end-up with a constant term.

E.g.

$$0,6,24,60,120,210,\cdots\\
6,18,36,60,90,\cdots\\
12,18,24,30,\cdots\\
6,6,6,6,\cdots$$

---

Alternatively, you can try and find a natural $d$ such that

$$\alpha:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^d}$$ is a finite number. If you find one, then repeat the process with

$$b_n:=a_n-\alpha n^d$$ and smaller degrees.

E.g., there is no finite $d$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^d}$$ exists.

Comment: Any reference? Any further reading?

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala: why ? You don't believe this ?

Comment: It is not about believing.  It is about substantiating.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala: what is difficult in my first sentence ? If you accept this sentence, the rest immediately follows.

Answer (score 2):

You're question is a bit imprecise, but here's one method. (That's not to say it's always possible to implement depending on how your sequence is defined.)

Suppose $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence. Then $f$ is a polynomial iff there exists $k$ such that $D^k(f) = 0 $ where
$$D(f)(n): = f(n+1) - f(n)  $$

Proof: Suppose $f$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. Then it should be easy to show that $D(f)$ is of degree $m-1$. By induction,  it's clear that $k = m+1$.

Suppose $D(f) = 0$. Then $ f(k) = f(k+1) $ so that $f$ is constant. $D^{k}(f) = 0$ then $D^{k-1}(f)$ is constant. You can show $D^{k-2}(f)$ is linear and so on to get that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$.

$D$ here is often called a difference operator and they play an analogous role to sequences that derivatives do to functions on $\mathbb{R}$.